# conditional covariance of $b$ and $\hat{\sigma}^{2}$

Tags: normal-distribution, least-squares, covariance, conditional

By definition of the normal linear model (i.e. standard linear regression under the assumption of gaussian noise with constant variance), we know that the regression coefficient vector $b$ is independent of the sum of squared residuals ($SSR$), and we know that $E(b)=\beta$, $E(\hat{\sigma}^{2})={\sigma}^{2}$ and $E(U_i|X_i)=0$. Hence, can we claim that the covariance of $b$ and $\hat{\sigma}^{2}$ conditional on $X_{i}=x_{i},i=1,2,...,n$ equals to zero, that is $cov(b,\hat{\sigma}^{2}|X_{i}=x_{i})=E(b,\hat{\sigma}^{2}|X_{i}=x_{i})-E(b|X_{i}=x_{i})E(\hat{\sigma}^{2}|X_{i}=x_{i})=0$

Thanks

Comment: Is $b$ the true parameter or its estimator?

Comment: it is the estimator for the coefficient vector $\beta$

Comment: My advice: look at Bruce Hansen, [Econometrics](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf). E.g., $\hat\beta$ and $\hat{e}$ are independent (§5.7), so "$\hat\beta$ is independent of any function of the residual vector including individual residuals $\hat{e}_i$ and the variance estimate $s^2$ and $\hat\sigma^2$" (§5.8).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See Wikipedia article “proofs involving ordinary least squares”. They are independent and for any independent random variables X and Y, their covariance is EXY-EX EY=0.